# How do I make a scatter brush in Illustrator that randomizes the tint and shade of elements in the brush?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to create a scatter brush in Illustrator CC that adjusts the tint and shade of the objects in the brush to give me a result like this:

[image]

Currently I can only get the scatter brush to look like this:

[image]

Here are my settings:

[image]

Is this possible? I have been searching online and haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a scatter brush using not only a circle but several with different shades of gray:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. It worked perfectly. I was wondering how brushes such as watercolor are made since they have different tints within the same brush stroke.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.**

Illustrator scatter brushes don't have any options to vary hue or tints.

Comment: This seems like such a simple thing for Adobe to have in Illustrator. I might have to give Affinity Designer a try.